# How to denied "bubble" selecting in WPF TreeView?

Tags: wpf, events, treeview, treeviewitem

I have a hierarchical TreeView object with some structure:

> - Main level
>
>   - second level 1
>   - second level 3
>   - second level 2

The problem is: when I select item on second level it fires "selected" event for Main level item. How can I denied it? I try use some tricks with boolean flag and original source property, but I failed it.
e.Handled = true also do not give me result.

Thanks for any advices and sorry for my bad English!

Comment: please post the relevant XAML and if possible code-behind as all.

Comment: I find bug. Main level event fires, when I use loading splashscreen in another gui thread (it started is another window in manual position). When I comment spashscreen calling it became normal :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some strange bug in my code. When I use splashscreen in my app, event for main level fires. When I disable splashscreen - it works perfectly with
e.Handled = true;
trick.

So I call second splashscreen in the end of item selected evend handler for 0 ms, and it works.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Events, added using AddHandler, ignore e.Handled flag, which is likely your case. Can you check if event's Source is equal to OriginalSource and if so quit the handler?